# Post Kendo grid data on form submit

Tags: excel, forms, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am looking for code that I can use to post the kendo grid data to controller on form submit.
Please Note: I cannot use JSON post because I have to use the grid data to create an excel file.
What I am trying to do in my jquery: Here UserRegistrationForm is my form name which contains the grid.

```
$("#UserRegistrationForm").submit();
```

Can you suggest how my controller action should look like to get the values of the grid.

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, I usually generate hidden fields with the grid's data before subbmiting the form. A simple way for do that:

```
$("#my-form").submit(function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        data = grid.dataSource.data(),
        columns = grid.options.columns.map(function(item) { return item.field; }),
        html = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var fields = Object.keys(data[i]);

        for (var n = 0; n < fields.length; n++) {
            if (columns.indexOf(fields[n]) > -1) {
                html+= "<input type='hidden' name='" + fields[n] + "[" + i + "]' value='" + data[i][fields[n]] + "' />";
            }
        }
    }

    $("#hidden-fields").empty().append(html);
});
```

[Working Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UxoME)

This will result in a set of hidden fields inside a div(`#hidden-fields`) that is also inside the form. Its names will be something like this:

```
name="PropertyA[0]" value="valueOfA0"
name="PropertyB[0]" value="valueOfB0"
name="PropertyA[1]" value="valueOfA1"
name="PropertyB[1]" value="valueOfB1" and so on...
```

This easily fits an ASP.Net MVC list parameter or in case of a list inside a ViewModel, just add the ViewModel's name before the property name, e.g. `ViewModel.PropertyA[0]`. For PHP it will result in an array e.g. `$_POST["PropertyA"]`. I'm not sure of other API languages.

Comment: Just a note: while the hidden field solution will work(I've done it), it does not work well for large data sets and will not work at all if you use grid paging as not all the rows are rendered at once.

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen what you mean with "does not work with for large data sets" ? Is there a certain amount of data that browsers or api can't handle well ? If you have set server paging in your grid, indeed, you can't deal with all data, since it's not entirely loaded, but if it isn't loaded there is no purpose on update it actually, as it wasn't chaged, right? Btw, if your grid is paged on client side the snippet above will work properly as the data is entirely loaded [check this](http://dojo.telerik.com/aXiYO).

Comment: Even client-side, only 1 page of data is rendered as html at a time.  The rest of the data is only is the dataSource.  So, the unrendered rows will not have their hidden input fields rendered either and thus will not be posted when the form is.  You would then require that your page size be large enough to render your largest dataset size which will eventually render too much html and the browser will start to chug.  In your example, if you were to add the hidden input rendering and then post the form(with the grid inside the form) only the current page's data would be posted.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/save-all-changes-with-one-request. I now use a variation of this to save all my grids as I do not like the built-in way that saves each collection in a separate request, preventing transactional processing. You can use this technique to merge the grid data with your form data and post it all at once using an ajax post instead of a $form.submit().  If you want me to elaborate, I will post a full answer with some of the code I currently use based on that Telerik Code Library entry.

Comment: sorry, I just realized that you were adding the hidden fields during submit() *not* during rendering(which is a technique that has been posted by telerik support in the past and can have the performance issues).

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen I agree with what you say about too much html would cause browser to crash, but this happens with any expressive amount of html elements, this is not a problem of my snippet; I don't think that in the example only the rendered page would be posted, as its relies on dataSource and - in client-side paging - the data is all loaded. You can see that in the dojo I've posted; The ajax question is out of scene, I think, as OP stated that *I cannot use JSON post* which I think he means ajax posting;

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen no problem. Anyway, OP didn't specified anything about paging, and I don't think he's using it actually, as he seems to the simulating an Excel sheet.